# ffmpeg on linux returns "HTTP error 403 forbidden", but in works on Windows

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, https

I am trying to download a video using ffmpeg. I get the link from "Kodi", and then use that link to get the full video. Before it worked great as the link that "Kodi" returned was a "http" link, but now, it returns "https" links.
The problem is that the link works great on my Windows PC(in which PC I also get the link from "Kodi"), but that link doesn't work on my linux vps(Ubuntu 16.04), as I get the message "http error 403 Forbidden".
Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here's some screenshots:

**Linux screenshot:**
[image]

**Windows screenshots:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots, please add **the text** to your question...

Answer (score 1):

It's common that an HLS link generated on one IP doesn't work on another IP. If you want to get a working URL for your VPS, generating a link on that VPS.

Another possible cause is geo-restriction. A video working in one country may not work in another country.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can't generate the link in my vps, and also, as far as I know, the link should also work where my vps is(France). Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If it's indeed IP limitation, I don't think there's a workaround. That's controlled by servers, not clients.
Here are some ideas: setup reverse SSH tunnels to download videos from your Win PC; installing VNC/X2go or use X forwarding so that you can use Kodi on the VPS, etc.